# How update row without using update query and View in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have doubt in SQL Server

My Question is:

I have two table named as Table1 and Table2

Table1:

```
 **ID       Name               Current_Address**
   44       John               44, T-Nagar, Chennai
```

Table2:

```
 **ID       Addreess**
   44      102, CIT Nagar, Chennai
   44      44, T-Nager, Channai
```

And my Question is:

> When i insert new address in Table2, Last Insert Address automatically
>   update in the Table1. But the difficulty is without using Update query
>   and View in SQL Server

Help....

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: what do You mean by " without using Update query" ?

Comment: Yes SonalPM.. Do u hv any idea..

Comment: Then try inventing something by your own.

Comment: You can use trigger to automate it, but inside that trigger is an UPDATE statement so it's unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

In case when You don't want `Update Query`, first delete data from `Table1` having id=44 and Use insert Query :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trigger here.

Try to use AFTER INSERT Trigger on Table2.

Comment: Ok, that's weird.
Get the values from Table1, then Delete that record, Insert to Table1 with all the old values with the new value of address from Table2.
I don't think you need an Update query here.